# Sort your list treemap by another list

Tags: java, list, treemap

Well, I saw other ways that involve list of arrays. Although nothing similar to this.

```
List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
orderList.add("ARMOR");
orderList.add("ADIDAS");
orderList.add("NIKE");

I have my List<TreeMap<Brand,String>> brands returning this list. 
[{NIKE=Shoes},{ADIDAS=Clothing},{ARMOR=Backpacks},{NIKE=Shorts}]
```

I want to sort this by the orderList provided to get the following:

```
[{ARMOR=Backpacks},{ADIDAS=Clothing},{NIKE=Shoes},{NIKE=Shorts}]
```

But I don't know how to. 
Perhaps there are other ways to modify this as a list and reorder it, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `List<String> orderList` to `HashMap<String, Integer> indexMap`:
`["ARMOR", "ADIDAS", "NIKE"]` -> `{"ARMOR": 0, "ADIDAS": 1, "NIKE": 2}`

```java
Map<String, Integer> indexMap = IntStream.range(0, orderList.size()) // [0, 1, 2]
         .boxed() // use int, not Integer
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> orderList.get(i), i -> i)); // add index to each element
```

Then, given `TreeMap<String, String> brands` you can do:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> result = brands.entrySet()
      .stream()
      .filter(entry -> indexMap.contains(entry.getKey()) // Remove elements not in indexMap... and therefore also not in orderList
      .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(indexMap.get(a.getKey()), indexMap(b.getKey()))) // Sort all present brands to match the order from orderList
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a customized `Comparator` directly with `Collections.sort()` method from the `java.util.Collections` API. Here is a copy-paste working example:

```java
public class SortByList {

    enum Brand {
        ADIDAS, ARMOR, NIKE
    }

    static class BrandMap extends TreeMap<Brand, String> {

        public BrandMap(Brand brand, String type) {
            put(brand, type);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderList.add("ARMOR");
        orderList.add("ADIDAS");
        orderList.add("NIKE");

        List<TreeMap<Brand, String>> brands = new ArrayList<>();
        brands.add(new BrandMap(Brand.NIKE, "Shoes"));
        brands.add(new BrandMap(Brand.ADIDAS, "Clothing"));
        brands.add(new BrandMap(Brand.ARMOR, "Backpacks"));
        brands.add(new BrandMap(Brand.NIKE, "Shorts"));

        brands.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            Brand key1 = o1.keySet().iterator().next();
            Brand key2 = o2.keySet().iterator().next();
            int index1 = orderList.indexOf(key1.name());
            int index2 = orderList.indexOf(key2.name());
            return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
        });

        //[{ARMOR=Backpacks},{ADIDAS=Clothing},{NIKE=Shoes},{NIKE=Shorts}]
        System.out.println(brands);

    }

}
```

**Just a note:** I've created `BrandMap` just to easily generate the test data and populate them to the list. You can leave it and just take the `Comparator` implementation written in lambda expression. It should work.

**Another update:** If you care about performance and your `orderList` is likely to get bigger in time, using `orderList.indexOf()` inside the sort function won't do good. Because it makes a sequential search which costs `O(N)` for each sorting comparison:

```java
brands.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    Brand key1 = o1.keySet().iterator().next();
    Brand key2 = o2.keySet().iterator().next();
    // extra iteration costs extra O(N)
    int index1 = orderList.indexOf(key1.name());
    // extra iteration costs extra O(N)
    int index2 = orderList.indexOf(key2.name());
    return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
});
```

If this is the case, I suggest to store your `orderList` in a `HashMap` instead of a `List` or `array` if you have the chance. Alternatively, you can convert it in a one time operation and use your map before your sorting operation:

```java
// this will cost O(N) only for once
Map<String, Integer> orderMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < orderList.size(); i++) {
    orderMap.put(orderList.get(i), i);
}

// then sort
brands.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    Brand key1 = o1.keySet().iterator().next();
    Brand key2 = o2.keySet().iterator().next();
    // now use the map for getting indices in constant O(1) time 
    int index1 = orderMap.get(key1.name());
    int index2 = orderMap.get(key2.name());
    return Integer.compare(index1, index2);
});
```

**A little extra:** Surely, storing in a `HashMap` costs an extra `O(N)` space but I assume memory consumption is tolerable in your case.

You're welcome. Cheers!

Comment: This looks really easy to follow. Thank you so much!